# How to exclude query results based on a blacklist

Tags: mysql, query

I have defined two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `devices` (
    `uuid` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `token` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `last_connected` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,        
    UNIQUE KEY(uuid, token)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `blacklist` (
    `uuid` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `cat_id` int(10) NOT NULL
);
```

The first table uses `uuid` and `token` as key, so the token of a device (identified by `uuid`) may change over time and it will keep track of it changing. The second table may contain 0 to many `category_id` values for a given`uuid`, and if a `token` is needed it is selected from the `devices` table, but if the `category` is listed in `blacklist` table it should not be in the result.

The tables are filled as follows:

`devices`:

```
+----+-----+-------------------+
|uuid|token|last_connected     |
+----+-----+-------------------+
|a   |t1   |2019-02-19T08:10:00| 
+----+-----+-------------------+
|a   |t2   |2019-02-19T08:12:00| 
+----+-----+-------------------+
|b   |ta   |2019-02-19T08:11:00| 
+----+-----+-------------------+
```

`blacklist`:

```
+----+------+
|uuid|cat_id|
+----+------+
|a   |1     |
+----+------+
|a   |3     |
+----+------+
|a   |7     |
+----+------+
|a   |5     |
+----+------+
```

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT token 
  FROM devices AS ad1 
  LEFT JOIN blacklist AS abl 
         ON ad1.uuid = abl.uuid 
 WHERE last_connected = (SELECT MAX(last_connected) 
                           FROM devices AS ad2 
                          WHERE ad1.uuid = ad2.uuid)
```

I get this result:

```
+-----+
|token|
+-----+
| t2  |
+-----+
| ta  |
+-----+
```

Which is almost what I want, what I want to add to the query is the possibility to exclude result `t2` if I add a restriction that the `uuid` may not be listed in `blacklist` for the given `cat_id` (the is will be inserted by php).

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT token 
  FROM devices AS ad1 
  LEFT JOIN blacklist AS abl 
         ON ad1.uuid = abl.uuid 
        AND abl.cat_id NOT IN (1) WHERE last_connected = (SELECT MAX(last_connected) 
                                                            FROM devices AS ad2 
                                                           WHERE ad1.uuid = ad2.uuid)
```

I added the `AND abl.cat_id NOT IN (1)` part where the 1 is inserted by php via a prepared statement.

The result however is this:

```
+-----+
|token|
+-----+
| t2  |
+-----+
| t2  |
+-----+
| t2  |
+-----+
| ta  |
+-----+
```

`t2` is in there thrice as opposed to not.

I have tried a few variants of this, but none of them work the way I want it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for the MINUS operation, which is not explicitly available on mysql, but can be emulated: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-minus/

Comment: Show us the desired output.  And make sure the data and result exemplifies the various edge cases.

Comment: Or [EXCEPT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/except/) in MariaDB-10.3

Comment: I have found the solution, thanks @jynus for pointing me towards the MINUS operation, it was part of the solution. 
I now have this query which works as intended:


`SELECT DISTINCT(ad1.uuid), ad1.token FROM devices AS ad1 LEFT JOIN blacklist AS abl ON ad1.uuid = abl.uuid AND abl.cat_id = %d WHERE last_connected = (SELECT MAX(last_connected) FROM devices AS ad2 WHERE ad1.uuid = ad2.uuid) AND abl.cat_id is null`